# Set Send buffer size of std::net::TcpStream in rust

Tags: tcp, rust

Tokio TcpStream has this - https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.12/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_recv_buffer_size

Is there an equivalent for std::net::TcpStream?

Answer (score 1):

While it is hard to prove a negative, browsing the docs and the source code, I'd bet there is no such function.

But it shouldn't be too difficult to write your own, using the `libc` crate, that does define the necessary [SO_RCVBUF](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.74/libc/constant.SO_RCVBUF.html) constant and [setsockopt](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.74/libc/fn.setsockopt.html) system call.